# Pass variable's value to function params?

Tags: javascript

I'm storing a function call in a variable.

```
var snippet = function { alert('a') };
snippet.call(); // Displays an alert
```

My problem is that I need to pass a variable as a param for the function.

```
var snippet;
function() {
   var word1 = 'hello';
   var word2 = ' world';
   snippet = function() { alert( word1 + word2 ); };
}
```

And when I call 'snippet' the variables are undefined:

```
snippet.call(); // Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

How can I save the function so that I save the values of `word1` and `word2` as it's params instead of the actual variables? (so I can later call it no matter if the vars are defined or not)

Comment: That doesn't look right...What's this for? What's the goal?

Comment: it's for a game. AI actions are stored in an array and executed on new frames. I couldn't copy all the code but that's the situation

Comment: This may just be a typo but the line `var snippet = function { alert( word1 + word2 ); };` is missing paranthesis after the keyword `function`. It should be `.. function () { ..`.

Comment: The syntax is the problem tho, you have an empty function that does nothing, the `snippet` variable is declared twice and what Tanzeel Kazi said.

Comment: I fixed the errors. The problems were just on the question not on the code. What I need is to turn the variables into static values somehow. Maybe saving them as `jQuery.extend(true, {}, word1),jQuery.extend(true, {}, word2)` would work? This makes me remember a problem I had with shallow copies but I don't know exactly how function params work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var snippet = function ( word1, word2 ) {
  alert ( word1 + word2 );
};

snippet ( "foo", "bar" );
// or
snippet.call ( ctx, "foo", "bar" ); // where `ctx` is the context you wish to use
```

More info on the `call()` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't clear but I have no way of knowing what was on the variables when I execute the snippet in the variable. I must save the variables so snippet.call() gets their values. This makes me remember a problem I had where the solution was to do a deep copy of the variable. Maybe saving them as `jQuery.extend(true, {}, word1),jQuery.extend(true, {}, word2)` would work?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't tell exactly where your question was going at the time of writing, but you could close over the two arguments in a closure returning function, like this:

```
var snippet = function (word1, word2) {
   return function() { alert( word1 + word2 ); };
};

snippet('hello', 'world').call();
```

The `snippest('hello', 'word')` returns a closure that you can then call or pass around. You can also create the closure immediately and create something slightly shorter:

```
var snippet = function(word1, word2) {
    return function() {
        alert(word1 + word2);
    };
}('hello', 'world');

snippet.call();
```

This is the same as earlier, but the outer function is immediately invoked and the resulting closure assigned to `snippet` which can then be called or passed around.

Comment: The problem is that the snippet is called without knowing what it contains. Maybe the question wasn't clear but I have no way of knowing what was on the variables when I execute the snippet in the variable. I must save the variables so snippet.call() gets their values. What I need is to turn the variables into static values somehow. Maybe saving them as `jQuery.extend(true, {}, word1),jQuery.extend(true, {}, word2)` would work? This makes me remember a problem I had with shallow copies but I don't know exactly how f() params work.

Comment: @Liso22 If the variables need to be returned by `.call()`, why not just do `return [word1, word2];` inside the closure? :)